# How to reduce space gap between header menu and main content body?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I want to know that how can I reduce the space gap after the header of the blog. Let me be specific, The space gap after the header menu and before the main content body.

I don't really have too much CSS knowledge, but after looking at the massive CSS code of the theme, I was a bit confused and decided not to play with the code. So, a little help needed here.

- Link - [Thats Breaking](http://thatsbreaking.com)
- Theme - Newspaper
- Blog platform - WordPress

Let me know if I missed any info.

Comment: What does it say in the inspector? It's padding, reduce the padding and you'll reduce the gap

Comment: currently in this  class .td-main-page-wrap padding-top is 40px you need to reduce in your custom css file and add .td-main-page-wrap { padding-top: 20px; }

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is set the margin or padding of the header or the body.

You can either use padding or margin, depends on the visual effect you want to get.

- [margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)
- [padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

*To get faster results, you can:*

1. In the web page  you linked righ-click on the body container you want to change the space gap
2. Look for this in the css code inspector:

   td-main-page-wrap {
   padding-top: 48px;
   }

Notice that the withe space is set with that attr.
For example, if you change that in the inspector from 48px, to 0px, automatically header and body content gaps together.

After that you shall change it in you css code. search for td-main-page-wrap.
You can change top, bottom, right or left Margin and Padding too.

Take care if you modify the css of the template, because the class or elements will probable be used in different views. Just in case you see all broken :p